# Keeping Count Of Words

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program to keep count of 'good' and 'bad' words.  The program is using two text files, one with good words and one with bad words, to detect the score.  I currently have the following:

...

The program executes in Python, but I can't get it to keep count of the score.  I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: What are you getting? Can you provide sample data.

Comment: the score should be -1 after the following:                                     Sentiment Analyzer 2.0
    Enter a sentence containing a positive or negative word or ENTER to   quit: bad
    Score:  0 is neutral.

Comment: Are the words in `NYC3-pos.txt` one per line and you've confirmed `good` is in that list?

Comment: They aren't one per line but they're not supposed to be for the assignment.  'good' is in that list.

Comment: `'good' in ['good great']` is `False`. You will need to split the words in your `load_words()` function. `'good' in ['good', 'great']` is `True`. `word_list.extend(line.strip().split())` may work if they are just space separated words.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious errors in the code. Here are some things to checks:

1) Do the lines in the pos/neg file have just one word?  If not, it needs to be split.

2) Is the case the same?  If not, be sure to casefold both the target words and the input text.

3) Use of *str.split()* usually isn't the best way to split natural text that might contain punctuation.  Consider something like `re.findall(r"[A-Za-z\'\-]+", text)`.

4) You will be much better lookup performance is the pos/neg words are stored in sets rather than lists.